# One-word synonym of 'fall short of'?

Tags: synonyms

Please do NOT rephrase or reword or rewrite the troubling sentence.
Are there any verbs **as a single word** that equates to [fall short (of)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fall-short-of?q=fall+short+of)
(and thus is an antonym of 'exceed') ?

Context: In [this question of mine](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/11/14) at Health SE, I want to stress (pun intended) that even calcium supplement doses FAR below the daily maximum, may still harm the heart. '**Fall short of**' implies that you're only hovering a little below the maximum; so I need a more extreme word.

> Are calcium supplements harmful, even if you **fall short of** the maximum dose?

Comment: *Fall short* doesn't mean "hovering a little below the *maximum*"; rather it means not attaining a desired or expected level. *The fundraisers fell short of their goal.*  And "exceed" does not have an antonym/opposite.

Comment: "even at a fraction of the dose" is probably the phrase I would use. Is there a reason other than brevity why you're looking for a single word? Exceeding a threshold is somewhat of a special context, so I'm not sure there's a specific word for staying well under the threshold. I'll think about it some more.

Comment: @ColleenV Thank you. The reason is only brevity, as you say. I was just hoping for a one-word antonym to 'exceed'. No worries at all.

Comment: There isn't one.

Answer (score 3):

No, not really.

"Fall short" doesn't actually mean what you think. It's a marginally idiomatic phrase that specifically implies *failure*. More literally, an arrow could *fall short* of the target. For you to fall short of the maximum dose, it implies that you did something that caused you to fail to reach it - not that you simply didn't take that much.

For this instance, you should rephrase the question. Try:

> Are calcium supplements harmful, even *below* the maximum dose?

This is actually shorter anyway. Optionally insert "always" before "harmful" Or:

> How much calcium is actually harmful?

Comment: Thanks, but can you please refrain from rephrasing my question or sentence (about which I didn't ask)? I elucidated this in my OP.

Answer (score -2):

I would go for [underachieve](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/underachieve) for one word. 'Fails to' in two.

Comment: what's wrong? is 'underachieve' a bad vibe word?

Comment: +1. I didn't downvote, instead I upvoted because 'underachieve' hadn't occurred to me. Thanks for the suggestion. However, 'Fails to' contains 2 words which I ask not about.

Comment: thanks, i just wrote it down so I don't forget! @LawArea51Proposal-Commit

Comment: You're welcome. Would you happen to know about other one-word synonyms?

Comment: in your context I would go for the plain English, 'you take less than the maximum dosage', which is actually 1 extra letter